# PHP: Stop the auto appending of @something.com for the "From" field using email

Tags: php, email, networking

I want to be able to send texts to phones via email (since each phone has their own address), and for specifying the from, I want to specify my own number, is there a way to do this?

For example:

```
$from = '7785555555';
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $from"))
  echo "Mail sent";
```

If I do this, the From in the email will be 7785555555@hostname.com. Is there any way I can send it so that it doesn't auto append the host name?

Thanks!
Shawn

Comment: I'd say it depends on your webhost's config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's better to use PHPMailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php)

See te example @ http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

In this part:

```
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
```

you can set te name and email for the from adress.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$from = '7785555555 <7785555555@hostname.com>';
```

Comment: That would still display an email address in the From.